# ::1 が ローカルホストのIPとなるのはなぜ？

Tags: linux, network

`/etc/hosts` の一覧において

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

とあり、 `127.0.0.1` が ローカルホストを意味する IPアドレスであることはインターネット上のルールとして知っていますが
`::1` はなぜ ローカルホストにループバックするのでしょう？

`::1` がIPとして有効なのか確かめるためにブラウザのアドレスバーに http://::1 と入力しましたがローカルホストには接続できませんでした。

初歩的な質問ですがどなかたわかる方いらっしゃいますか？

Comment: 127.0.0.1はIPv4, ::1はIPv6のアドレスです。取り急ぎ、コメントで。

Comment: IPv6の場合http://[::1]と括弧でくくる必要があります

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IPv4上の `127.0.0.1` と同様、`::1` はIPv6上でlocalhostを表すループバックアドレスです。

IPv6アドレスは128ビットを8つに分けて16進数で表記されるので `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001` ですが、[各ブロック先頭の0を省略できる、連続した0のブロックは`::`で省略できる](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9#.E6.8E.A8.E5.A5.A8.E3.81.95.E3.82.8C.E3.81.9F.E3.83.86.E3.82.AD.E3.82.B9.E3.83.88.E8.A1.A8.E7.8F.BE)という決まりがあるため、 `::1` と表記できます。

IPv4アドレスと異なり、IPv6アドレスの区切り文字であるコロンは、URLにおいてはホスト名とポート番号の区切りにも使われています。そのため、URLに書く際は `[]` で囲むルールになっています。

よって、 http://[::1]/ と入力すればブラウザでもアクセスできるかと思います。

参考 [IPv6アドレス - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9)